# Spark vs Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, batch-processing, apache-spark, transformation

I have a requirement to write Big Data processing application using either Hadoop or Spark. I understand that Hadoop MapReduce is best technology for batch processing application while Spark is best technology for analytic application. 
Application will get a input file and few configuration file. This input file need to be transformed to a output file with help of config files. Config file or transformation specification as we call has information like mapping from source to target file column wise and expression to transform  particular cell value to other value. I have written this already with MapReduce. Input may contain million / billion of records. Now stakeholders are suggesting to use Spark as they feel it is faster than MapReduce. But I think for this scenario Spark will be not suitable as it is good for analytic application not for batch processing. Also I could see only API in Spark which is like aggregate function, unable to find any inbuilt API to read / record by record and column by column like MapReduce. Please suggest your approach on this
[image: Source Input File which needs to be transformed with given configuration]

[image: Generated output with given input and config]

Comment: I suggest reading through the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/

Comment: I know basic of Spark but wanted to know if Spark can be faster for batch processing application than MapReduce. I know Spark is good for analytic application

Comment: For what it's worth, `flatMap` followed by `reduceByKey` in Spark is logically equivalent to the standard MapReduce in Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out of your vacation :). As per documentation Spark is 100 times faster than MapReduce? So being suggested to use Spark. Still I feel MR is best batch processing framework while Spark is good for analytics application

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely right. Spark is a good tool, but its not yet ready for enterprise use. Spark can be faster than Hadoop even 100x on some corner cases, when all the data fits in memory and there are series of complex transformations to be applied. If it is the typical batch processing case with some flat logic set by configuration file, I'd recommend you to use Hadoop as you won't have much performance gain with Spark. Hadoop is much more mature and fault tolerant, it is much higher adopted and free of bugs than Spark. I would consider you to be on a safe route and have Hadoop cluster with HDFS to store the data and YARN, write you application in Java as a mapreduce job and play with Spark on the same cluster - you would see the difference on your specific case without much efforts